# How to insert the sum of every 2 vectors between those vectors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How to insert the sum of every 2 vectors between them?
Example:

```
[[10,10], [20,30], [1,1]] -----> [[10,10], [30,40], [20,30], [21,31], [1,1]]
```

I guess i'll first make a numpy array to get the sums, but i'm not sure how to insert the new vectors in the right places. Do I do this on array or should I convert the sums back to list?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate sums and then use the function `insert`:

```
arr = np.array([[10,10], [20,30], [1,1]])

arr1 = arr[::2] + arr[1::2]
arr2 = np.insert(arr, np.arange(1, arr.shape[0]), arr1, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[10, 10],
       [30, 40],
       [20, 30],
       [21, 31],
       [ 1,  1]])
```